# Mouseover mouseleave translateY does not repeat

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use a function in jquery where I use mouseover to appear a div from top, and mouseleave to make it disappear. I am able to do this once, but then if I do mouseover again does not work anymore.

html

```
<div id="box">
<div id="box_appear"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#box{position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; overflow:hidden}
#box_appear{position:absolute; width:300px; height:300px; transform:translateY(-100%); top:0;left:0}

@keyframes slideInDown {
from {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
visibility: visible;
}

to {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
 }

.slideInDown {
 -webkit-animation-name: slideInDown;
 animation-name: slideInDown;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
 animation-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes slideInUp {
from {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
visibility: visible;
}

to {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}
}

.slideInUp {
-webkit-animation-name: slideInUp;
animation-name: slideInUp;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

jquery

```
$('#box').on('mouseover', function () {

   $('#box_appear').addClass('slideInDown');


});
$('#box').on('mouseleave', function () {       
       $('#box_appear').addClass('slideInUp');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an optimization tip but since you're calling `$('$box_appear')` so many times I'd cache it to reduce the lookups. You could also do the same #or `$('#box')`.

As far as your main problem You need to remove the classes added upon `mouseover/mouseleave`. Otherwise they'll negate each other:

```
$box = $('#box');
$boxAppear = $('#box_appear');

$box.on('mouseover', function () {
  $boxAppear
    .removeClass('slideInUp')
    .addClass('slideInDown');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $boxAppear
    .removeClass('slideInDown');
    .addClass('slideInUp');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do `AddClass` in both routines; causing the inner div to end up with both classes after mousing over the parent.

Solution: use `removeClass` in the mouseout routine rather than adding a second class.